# How to create an .exe installer that installs react-electron-build and run a java-rest-api as a background service

Tags: java, reactjs, windows-installer, desktop-application, electron-builder

Want to make an custom Windows Installer of a Product with

- Front End: A separate exe file available made from electron to convert a react application to a desktop application. Also, Need an option in the react app called "Restart Service" that actually restarts the API running as Background Service.
- Backend Service: Have a jar file available made in springboot. It needs to be available always in the background. Frontend may or may not utilise but it should run. We need this service to listen to incoming messages from a google pub/sub messaging queue and run appropriate interaction with a COM library.

So we want to package everything in such a way that everything is installed and front end application is available as an application icon on the desktop that user can run as needed.

- Front End:Was able to create a seperate exe for front end with electron library

[Installation files looks like this for react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeWft.png)

- Backend: I have no idea how to proceed with packaging java project with req runtime env.

Finally, How to create a single installer for both of this.